# How often can we use Tyr's Challenge?

Tags: blood-rage

If all villages are pillaged, can we use the *Tyr's Challenge* card as our action?

> **Tyr's Challenge**
>
> You may pay 2 rage to repillage an already pillaged village

If we can afford the rage for the action, how often can we use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the rage and you have the card, you can do it as often as you like.

The cards are not limited in their use except when specifically stated.

Note that if all provinces are pillaged, the round ends, and you can't use *Tyr's Challenge* even if you could afford it.

Comment: are you sure ?
because its so important .

If all villages are pillaged . Can all player move?
even march or put the upgrade cards or quest ?

Comment: @omidamir Players can't move or do anything in a round if everything's already pillaged. If you wanted to use the ability over and over you'd have to lock down a region so that it wouldn't get pillaged, then use the ability in other areas.

Comment: To disambiguate: yes, I'm absolutely sure that the game works this way. The rules are very clear and very simple. You use a card unless told otherwise. You stop all action after all regions are pillaged unless told otherwise.