# What are the limitations on pillaging and battling a region?

Tags: blood-rage

How many times we can pillage or battle each region **without** using the Tyr's Challenge card ("As your action, you may pay 2 rage to repillage an already pillage")?
Is there a limitation?

Comment: Wow, can't believe my reading is so bad. Thanks @doppelgreener for adding the emphasis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How often can we use Tyr's Challenge?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42125/how-often-can-we-use-tyrs-challenge)

Answer (score 2):

The rules for Blood Rage describe the phases of play, in particular with page 17:

> To Pillage, choose a province that has at least one of your figures in it (or in a supporting fjord) and has not yet been successfully pillaged this phase (its Pillage token is showing the reward side up).

Ipso facto, each province may be pillaged repeatedly until a pillage is successful, and then it cannot be pillaged again.